# I find a advanced video editor for Ubuntu

Tags: video, video-editor, editor, editing

I need a video editor which has the next functions:

- move the video (like move tool on gimp)
- resize the video (like scale tool on gimp)
- rotate the video (like rotate tool on gimp)
- and color combination like this:
  [image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Some of the options that you have:

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/).  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install avidemux
```

[Cinelerra](http://www.heroinewarrior.com/cinelerra.php)

[OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/).  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openshot openshot-doc
```

On a personal note, I recommend, and use OpenShot, and I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) (even though it is meant to be a animation renderer) has a very good non-linear video editor.

```
sudo apt-get install blender
```

There many other [video-editors](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Precise_Video) to choose from.